# SQL Server query to show tasks running concurrently

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that records tasks run withing our application. It has 3 relevent columns; TaskName, StartDateTime, and EndDateTime.

I need to write a query that will show what tasks are running being run at the same time.

For example

```
       **TaskName  |      StartDateTime      |  EndDateTime**
          Task1      2014-08-18 11:16:29.000    2014-08-18 11:19:29.000
          Task2      2014-08-18 11:17:29.000    2014-08-18 11:17:34.000        
          Task3      2014-08-18 11:18:29.000    2014-08-18 11:18:52.000
          Task4      2014-08-18 11:18:53.000    2014-08-18 11:21:12.000
```

Per my example, while Task1 is running Task2, and Task3 start and finish before Task 1 has finished. Task4 starts before task1 finishes but finishes after Task1 completes.

I want to be able to see the concurrent tasks to better analyze performance issues.

I don't even know where to start, if there is a example somewhere I can look at that would probably be enough for me to figure it out.

Comment: You need to break the task down somehow. I'd probably begin by specifying a span of time, and then querying for tasks that begin or finish in between that time span. Then you can look into figuring out how to programatically select time spans to query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?  I left some commented-out portions in case you want to retrieve the data from both sides.

```
DECLARE @StackOverflow TABLE (TaskName VARCHAR(5), StartDateTime DATETIME, EndDateTime DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @StackOverflow (TaskName, StartDateTime, EndDateTime)


SELECT 'Task1','2014-08-18 11:16:29.000','2014-08-18 11:19:29.000' UNION 
SELECT 'Task2','2014-08-18 11:17:29.000','2014-08-18 11:17:34.000' UNION         
SELECT 'Task3','2014-08-18 11:18:29.000','2014-08-18 11:18:52.000' UNION 
SELECT 'Task4','2014-08-18 11:18:53.000','2014-08-18 11:21:12.000' 

SELECT * FROM @StackOverflow

SELECT a.TaskName + ' begins while ' + b.TaskName + ' is running' Result--, a.*, b.* 
FROM 
    @StackOverflow a
     INNER JOIN 
    @StackOverflow b ON 
        a.TaskName <> b.TaskName AND 
        a.StartDateTime BETWEEN b.StartDateTime AND b.EndDateTime 
--UNION 
--SELECT b.TaskName + ' begins while ' + a.TaskName + ' is running'--, a.*, b.*
--FROM 
--  @StackOverflow a
--   INNER JOIN 
--  @StackOverflow b ON 
--      a.TaskName <> b.TaskName AND 
--      a.EndDateTime BETWEEN b.StartDateTime AND b.EndDateTime 
ORDER BY Result
```

> Result
>
> Task2 begins while Task1 is running
>
> Task3 begins while Task1 is running
>
> Task4 begins while Task1 is running

Comment: This works, I changed it to a CTE as the above was taking 10+ min due to the size of my table. Thank you!